# Managed C# App passing string as empty byte[] for some odd reason... IronPDF

Tags: c#, arrays, revit

I'm having a very odd issue when attempting to call a method from the Nuget Package IronPDF.
    Based on the symptoms and the fact that I can't find anyone else on the internet who has encountered this issue, I'm assuming it's not the package's fault.

---

Basically, whenever I call "HtmlToPdf.RenderHtmlAsPdf()" in a console app, everything works fine, but when I run it as a managed application through Revit 2018 (as an addin), the method freaks out and returns the following System.IO.IOException:
[image]

```
System.IO.IOException: 'Can not parse a PDF from an empty byte array.'
```

To me, it's 100% clear I'm correctly passing it a string in BOTH scenarios & the documentation clearly states that it takes only a string ([IronPDF Documentation](https://ironpdf.com/c%23-pdf-documentation/html/M_IronPdf_HtmlToPdf_RenderHtmlAsPdf_1.htm)), but somehow it thinks it's receiving an empty byte array!!!!??? How weird!!!

If you know any reason why running a C# application as managed through an external application would cause strings to be read as byte arrays, please help!

Comment: I'm getting teh same exception. It works in my ASP.Net Core 2.2 app locally (win10), but when it runs on ECS in a linux container, it thows up. I tried bot this method, and its asynchronous twin.

Comment: I rolled back to NuGet version 5.2.0, and it's still throwing the same error. I think it's time to switch libraries.

Comment: if you are running on windows server perhaps unblocking the IronPdf.DLL will help solve this issue (under the file properties dialog) - this solved the same error i had

Comment: I have the same issue running a console app on Windows Server 2012R2. Did you find a solution for it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about Revit addins, but I would guess you are missing some dependencies. I was getting the exact same exception, because when I built my Docker container (running linux), I was missing several.

Iron PDF documents this specific issue here:

https://ironpdf.com/docs/questions/docker-linux/

[image]